# single sign on (sso) for existing applications

Tags: single-sign-on

I have multiple applications (made with different tech such as .NET, JSP, PHP, ... ). Each one of them have its proper login page which contacts the LDAP to verify the username and password (there is one LDAP for all the applications).

What I want is to do a SSO for these apps: One login page is to "rule them all".

1. The user enters his credentials once.
2. He chooses an app from list.
3. The app will load without accessing the original login page.

My additional questions are:
Is there anyway to implement a SSO solution without modifying the apps's source code? 
Is there a trick to pass the username and password to the original login page and submit automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You need an IdP, something like [Shibboleth IdP](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/IDP30/Installation) or ADFS, which will handle the users from an Authentication Source and do that hard stuff like the login page, etc. Usually there's user management headaches here, i.e. how will users change their passwords, etc. That's where a commercial solution like [Okta](https://www.okta.com/products/single-sign-on/), Ping, or OneLogin might work better for you.

You need a SAML Service Provider for each of your apps (what SAML stack you choose largely depends upon tech used in site), or you can use something like Shibboleth SP which simply protects paths on the webserver. If the apps are all on the same one or two web servers, go with Shib, as it'll make the integration with ADFS simpler.

If you want to avoid modifying source code, something like [Shibboleth SP](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/Home) is probably for you... it protects paths, and loads user attributes into server variables you can pull from (i.e. username, first name, last name, etc.) to render on your app.